# Asignar eventos a un elemento cuando se utiliza el append - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, html-select

estoy usando el plugin "bootstrap-select" con el siguiente elemento

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Single Select">
    <option disabled selected>Single Option</option>
    <option value="2">Foobar</option>
    <option value="3">Is great</option>
    <option value="4">Is awesome</option>
    <option value="5">Is wow</option>
    <option value="6">Boom !</option>
</select>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es crear esto dinamicamente usando JQuery con el metodo "append", pero cuando lo utilizo, se me crea normal el select, **pero no le asigna los eventos que tiene el plugin** (Los estilos, la funcionalidad, etc).
Utilizo un boton para crear el select dinamico:

```
<button onclick="CrearSelects()"></button>
```

Y lo llamo con esa funcion

```
function CrearSelects()
{
  crear_select = '<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Single Select">';
  crear_select += '<option disabled selected>Single Option</option>';
  crear_select += '<option value="3">Is great</option>';
  crear_select += '<option value="4">Is awesome</option>';
  crear_select += '<option value="5">Is wow</option>';
  crear_select += '<option value="6">Boom !</option></select>';
  
  $('#div_selects').append(crear_select);
}
```

Lo que quiero que me muestre

[image: El select del plugin]

Lo que me muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El plugin esta llamado inicialmente, por lo que si cre el mismo elemento con solo HTML, si funciona correctamente

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir que *"no le asigna los eventos que tiene el plugin"*?

Comment: @A.Cedano me refiero a los estilos que tiene, la funcionalidad, etc

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que esto no se crea en el `select`: `class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Single Select"`? Por favor pulsa en [edit] y aclara, porque la pregunta es confusa.  ¿Qué debería mostrarse? ¿qué se muestra?

Comment: Listo @A.Cedano como ves solo me aparece eso en display: none, cuando lo agrega con el append

Comment: @JuanRivera, has probado a llamar al plugin una vez has creado el select? *$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();*

Comment: @cooper Mmm, lo estoy llamando desde el principio (Lo inicio en el  Head), lo llamo otra vez? Digo, estoy usando una plantilla y todos los componentes ya estan especificados y separados por estilos, script, contenido, etc

Comment: No entiendo mucho todavía. Pero la imagen del final no tiene nada que ver con lo otro, ahí se ve algo como `data-live-search` etc que no es parte de lo que estás creando en la función. ¿No tienes nada más en el elemento con `id="div_selects"`?

Comment: @A.Cedano es el mismo selectpicker solo agregando esa opcion, la cosa es que me sale eso cuando uso el append, no carga los estilos y no se asigna la funcionalidad, el link del plugin puedes verlo aca: [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/), esas "animaciones", estilos ,etc no me sale nada

Comment: @A.Cedano Es como si creo un elemento cualquier en el HTML y le pongo como background-color: red y creo ese mismo elemento con el mismo estilo utilizando el append, no me pone los estilos

Comment: Pero ¿si ya hay un `select` por qué creas de nuevo un `select` completo en la función?

Comment: @A.Cedano El select de la funcion estoy aputando a un div, por eso dice `$('#div_selects').append(crear_select);` Por eso puse en la pregunta, quiero crear esto dinamicamente, refiriendome al select de la funcion

Comment: Si ejecutas esto `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` después de que haces el append, el problema que veo es que si lo declaras al inicio arma el combo en base a lo que tengas en ese momento, no se arma dinámico.

Comment: @JuanRivera, sí, deberías llamarlo una vez el select que has creado pertenezca al DOM. Es decir, cuando figure como una más de las etiquetas HTML que tendrás en ese momento en tu página.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea Si, era eso, gracias, no se explicarme muy bien pero igualmente agradezco a todos